# How do I control the subscription count in RxJava 2?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a long running task (say an `Observable<Integer>`) that I want to trigger as few times in my application as possible. I have multiple "views" on the task that process the events that it sends in various ways. I only have one `subscribe` in my entire application.

**How do I ensure that the long running task is only triggered once for each subscription, and is only triggered when required by a subscription?**

To make things more concrete, here is a unit-test:

```
@Test
public void testSubscriptionCount() {

    final Counter counter = new Counter();

    // Some long running tasks that should be triggered once per subscribe
    final Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> {
            counter.increment();
        });

    // Some "view" on the long running task
    final Observable<Integer> b = a.filter(x -> x % 2 == 0);

    // Another "view" on the long running task
    final Observable<Integer> c = a.filter(x -> x % 2 == 1);

    // A view on the views
    final Observable<Integer> d = Observable.zip(b, c, (x, y) -> x + y);

    d.toList().blockingGet();

    assertEquals(1, counter.count); // Fails, counter.count == 2
}
```

I would like `a` to only be triggered when one of its views (`b`, `c` or `d`) is subscribed to, but also only once per subscription.

In the code above, the subscription happens twice (I presume that `d` triggers `b` and `c`, which both trigger `a` independently).

---

Adding `.share()` does not solve the problem (although I think it is along the right lines):

```
    // Some long running tasks that should be triggered once per subscribe
    final Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> counter.increment())
        .share();
```

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>
> Expected :1
>
> Actual   :2

Comment: It's not clear to me what the phrase "is only triggered when required" means. Do you have unit tests for that?

Comment: I mean the observable should only run its emitter code when someone subscribes either to it directly or to some other observable that is built from it.

Comment: What you are describing is how Observables work. Do you have some reason to believe that they don't work that way?

Comment: I thought they worked that way too, but in my test `counter.increment()` is called twice.

Comment: You *are* subscribing twice. The `b` chain subscribes once and the `c` chain subscribes once. In @Matt's answer, he describes using `share` to ensure only a single subscription.

Comment: @sdgfsdh There are 2 subscriptions, no matter if each one triggers a new data set to be emitted or not. `share()` will do what you want, and your issue is how you count subscriptions. There will always be 2 subscriptions in your case. You should rather count that there are 5 items emitted only, rather than 10.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to prevent multiple executions when the observer is subscribed in parallel, `.share()` is what you are looking for:

```
Observable<Integer> shared = source.share();

// In thread 1:

shared.subscribe(...);

// In thread 2:

shared.subscribe(...);
```

So long as the source observable has not yet completed when second subscription happens, it will receive the same results as the first, and will not force another execution of the source observable.

The RxJava documentation has much more detailed explanation, but it's basically a wrapper that has some reference counting and only subscribes to the source observable when necessary to avoid concurrent executions.

Also keep in mind that timing will play an important part in which values are actually delivered.  I don't believe `.share()` will do any specific buffering of elements, so if elements are delivered prior to the second subscription the second subscription will not get those elements.  You'd have to use `.buffer()` or some other means of holding onto results for late subscribers.

Comment: I think `.share()` is the right idea, but it still gives me two subscribes (see edit).

Comment: Yes, it's going to give you two subscribes, because your operation is not long running.  If you add a .delay(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) in before the .doOnSubscribe, it does exactly what you want.  Share is meant to prevent concurrent executions.  In your case, it finishes too quickly for the two executions to be shared.

Comment: I see. Is there a variant that is like `share` but does not subscribe again after the first trigger?